# NoReverseMatch found

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am using django 1.7 & python 3.4
I am trying to implement follow and unfollow a user into my website but i am stuck.
urls.py

```
url(r'^user/', include('myuserprofile.urls'),),
```

myuserprofile.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'myuserprofile.views.profile', name='profile'),
                       url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/follow/$', 'myuserprofile.views.follow', name='follow'),
                       url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/unfollow/$', 'myuserprofile.views.unfollow', name='unfollow'),
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def follow(request):
    myuser = request.user.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        to_user = MyUser.objects.get(id=request.POST['to_user'])
        rel, created = Relationship.objects.get_or_create(
            from_user=myuser.myuserprofile,
            to_user=to_user,
            defaults={'status': 'following'}
        )
else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/'))

            if not created:
                rel.status = 'following'
                rel.save()
```

and the template portion is like this:

```
<form action="{% if relationship.status == 'F' %}{% url 'unfollow' %}{% else %}{% url 'follow' %}{% endif %}" method="POST">
```

Reverse for 'follow' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P[^/]+)/follow/$']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the username of the user to follow/unfollow:

```
{% url 'follow' user_to_follow.username %}
```

Change the `urls.py` to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myuserprofile.views',
         url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/$', 'profile', name='profile'),
         url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/follow/$', 'follow', name='follow'),
         url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/unfollow/$', 'unfollow', name='unfollow'),
)
```

And the signature of the view should accept the `username` argument:

```
@login_required
def follow(request, username):
    myuser = request.user.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        to_user = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [namespaced URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).
In your case the URL `unfollow` should be referenced as `<app_name>:unfollow`.

Comment: I tried that also. even that is showing the same error

Comment: The URL pattern requires a parameter `slug` to compute the full url it can be passed in the template using `{% url 'myuserprofile:unfollow' <user_slug> %}`

Answer (score 0):

> URL namespaces allow you to uniquely reverse named URL patterns even
>   if different applications use the same URL names. It’s a good practice
>   for third-party apps to always use namespaced URLs (as we did in the
>   tutorial). Similarly, it also allows you to reverse URLs if multiple
>   instances of an application are deployed. In other words, since
>   multiple instances of a single application will share named URLs,
>   namespaces provide a way to tell these named URLs apart

have a look on this [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

you have to use `URL namespaces`

here is my

polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    ...
)
```

so we have use like

```
{% url 'polls:index' %}
```

Comment: yes, I tried that. it's showing 'myuserprofile' is not a registered namespace even when i updated the url: url(r'^user/', include('myuserprofile.urls', namespace='myuserprofile'))

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the slug in your template.

```
<form action="{% if relationship.status == 'F' %}{% url 'unfollow' %}{% else %}{% url 'follow' %}{% endif %}" method="POST">
```

It should be

```
<form action="{% if relationship.status == 'F' %}{% url 'unfollow' user.username %}{% else %}{% url 'follow' user.username %}{% endif %}" method="POST">
```